# Grails-ish way to model Users with emails on different networks

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What I have is a set of Users and a set of Networks, and those users need to have different email addresses on the various networks -- some are internal, some are external, some are development, and they've all got their own naming & addressing schemes.

What I have so far is this, simplified, with extraneous code removed:

```
class Network {

    String name

    static hasMany = [email: Email]

}

class User {

    String login

    static hasMany = [email: Email]

}

class Email {

    string address

    static belongsTo = [user: User, network: Network]

}
```

Where I'm struggling a bit, assuming this is the right way to construct this relationship, is with how to address the email addresses for a given user and network. For example, in a user creation page:

```
<g:each
    in="${com.damascusgrp.dto.Network.findAll()}">
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'email', 'error')} required">
        <label for="email">
            ${it.name} 
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:field type="email" name="email" required="" value="${userInstance?.email}"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

But while I'm certain that "value" is incorrect, I just can't wrap my head around what it ought to be. Call it Java preventing me from properly thinking in Groovy.

Or is there a more grails-ish way to do this altogether that I've completely missed? I'm upgrading this code from a single email address as part of the User class to this and while I considered making a HashMap that lived within User, I wanted to try this first.

-----Update-----

I created an empty project with just the three classes as listed above and let Grails build controllers & views for them to see what it would do. What I've modified from that appears below:

```
<ul class="one-to-many">
    <g:each in="${userInstance?.email?}" var="e">
        <li><g:link controller="email" action="show" id="${e.id}">${e?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></li>
    </g:each>
    <li class="add">
        <g:link controller="email" action="create" params="['user.id': userInstance?.id]">${message(code: 'default.add.label', args: [message(code: 'email.label', default: 'Email')])}</g:link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I took this basically verbatim from the scaffolded view and folded it into my code. I just now need to figure out how to "hide" the user field from the email creation page, or better yet do this all on one page using JQuery or something like that. Or switch to a Map as was suggested.

------2nd Update-----

Instantiating is the only remaining issue. When I try to instantiate this, and add a new Email to it, I get an NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method collectEntries() on null object
    at com.damascusgrp.dto.User.getEmailsByNetwork(User.groovy:37)
    at com.damascusgrp.dto.UserSpec.Fully constructed user is good(UserSpec.groovy:44)
```

I've tried various ways to pre-load this, or set it up with blank entries for each of the defined networks, but nothing has worked right yet. Here's the code as it stands now, with Ian's help in place.

```
class User {

    String login
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String filePath
    static hasMany = [requests:Request, email: Email]

    static transients = ['emailsByNetwork']  

    def User(String l) {
        login = l
    }

    def getName() {
        "${firstName} ${lastName}"
    }

    String toString() {
        login
    }

    static constraints = {
        login blank:false, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/, unique:true
        password blank:false, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/
        firstName blank:false
        lastName blank:false
        filePath blank:false 
    }

    Map getEmailsByNetwork() {
        email.collectEntries { [(it.network.id), it] }
    }

    def addToEmail(Email em) {
        email[em.network.id] = em 
    }

}
```

Comment: i assume there is finite/slowly changing number of networks?  i'd prop this up in the controller to something looking like a map for the view and then the other way around on saving the user.  or at least provide some getter/setter in your domain to keep your view code clean.  if you want to keep it like that: you need an accessor to get the email by network in your User and you have to name the email fields in the loop distinct (e.g. email-in-${network.name}) - never rely on the order of things.

Comment: The number of networks is finite, but will vary from installation to installation, so it's not something I can pre-determine or determine just once. I've gotten closer by creating an experimental project with just these three classes and playing around a bit, but things still aren't working as elegantly as I'd like. I'll edit the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample GSP suggests that the domain model has each `User` with exactly one `Email` on each `Network` - a `User` can't have two different `Email` objects on the same `Network`.  So I'd add a transient property to the `User` domain class

```
class User {

    String login

    static hasMany = [email: Email]

    Map getEmailsByNetwork() {
      (email?.collectEntries { [it.network.id, it] }) ?: [:]
    }

    static transients = ['emailsByNetwork']

}
```

Now `user.emailsByNetwork` will be a map from `Network` id to `Email`, and in the GSP you can say

```
<g:set var="emailsByNet" value="${userInstance.emailsByNetwork}" />
<g:each var="net"
    in="${com.damascusgrp.dto.Network.findAll()}">
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: emailsByNet[net.id], field: 'email', 'error')} required">
        <label for="net_${net.id}_email">
            ${net.name} 
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:field type="email" name="net_${net.id}_email" required="" value="${emailsByNet[net.id]?.email}"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

In the controller that receives this form post you'll have to handle the various `params.net_1_email` etc. appropriately, updating the existing `emailsByNetwork[n]` if it exists or `userInstance.addToEmail(new Email(network:Network.load(n), email:value))` if not.

Comment: Perfect. Now I just need to spend some time understanding this. It's very elegant and I want to be sure I "get" it so it ends up getting carried forward in the rest of my code. Thanks, Ian.

Comment: Ian, I notice that this solution produces a slight problem when instantiating a new User; the getEmailsByNetwork() call fails because the email map is null -- what's the right way to get that initialized? I'll edit my OP to show the current state of the object. I'm so close now I can taste it, but the various ways I've tried all feel wrong so far.

Comment: @Bret you definitely shouldn't implement `addToEmail` yourself, that's provided automatically by Grails, also note that the `email` property in `User` is a _set_, not a _map_ (I would personally have named it "emails" rather than "email" - hasMany associations usually have plural names).

Comment: @Bret I've edited my answer with an example of one way you could make `getEmailsByNetwork` return an empty map if `email` is null.

Comment: Ahhh. There's so much the books I have don't cover, apparently. I've been struggling with the "email/emails" name and will change it shortly as it feels better plural, you're right.

Comment: I was trying to use the "?" operator, but not in the right place. I get what you're doing now. Thanks again, Ian.